# Difference between multiple ISO 8601 to ZonedDateTime parsing methods

Tags: java, datetime, parsing, zoneddatetime

I am trying to validate and store date times with any offset into the database in UTC.

For validation, I am using

```java
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME.parseUnresolved(dateString, new ParsePosition(0));
```

When called with an offset of -25:00, this throws `java.time.DateTimeException: Value out of range: Hour[0-23], Minute[0-59], Second[0-59]`. For any other invalid strings, this returns **null**.

But when I am trying to parse it using

```java
ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString)
```

when using a correct offset of -23:00, this throws `Text '2012-04-23T18:25:43.511-23:00' could not be parsed: Zone offset not in valid range: -18:00 to +18:00`. If I look up the method definition, it seems like it is using the same parsing method `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`

```java
public static ZonedDateTime parse(CharSequence text) {
    return parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
}
```

My question is, why are there different offset limits for parsing an ISO 8601 date times ?

Comment: One is `parse` and the other is `parseUnresolved`. Do you realise these are different methods?

Comment: @Sweeper My understanding of `parseUnresolved` what that it is "faster" and only returns `TemporalAccessor`, not a ZonedDateTime. What is the difference then ? I cannot find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#resolving) describes this difference here:

> Parsing is implemented as a two-phase operation. First, the text is parsed using the layout defined by the formatter, producing a Map of field to value, a ZoneId and a Chronology. **Second, the parsed data is resolved, by validating, combining and simplifying the various fields into more useful ones.**
>
> Five parsing methods are supplied by this class. Four of these perform both the parse and resolve phases. The fifth method, `parseUnresolved(CharSequence, ParsePosition)`, **only performs the first phase**, leaving the result unresolved. As such, it is essentially a low-level operation.

So the thing that `parseUnresolved` does not do, but `parse` does, is "validating [...] the various fields". In this case, `parse` checks that the offset is within `ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS.range()` (±18 hours). `parseUnresolved` doesn't do this, just like how it doesn't check whether month 20 is a valid month:

```
System.out.println(
    // this returns a non-null value
    DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.parseUnresolved(
        "2021-20-20", new ParsePosition(0)
    )
);
```

`DateTimeException` is also a [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseUnresolved-java.lang.CharSequence-java.text.ParsePosition-) exception that `parseUnresolved` can throw.

> **Throws:**
>
> `DateTimeException` - if some problem occurs during parsing

It just so happens that `parseUnresolved` doesn't recognise anything more than 24 hours as an offset when parsing an offset, during "the first phase".